# unable to connect remote desktop after installing active directory

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

i have a co-location server on a data center. 5-10 web sites and sql server were running on it. After installation of active directory remotely, I am not able to login via remote desktop and also web sites are down.
First i need to login my server again and rerun sql server and iis.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the server rebooted properly? What's the state on the console?

Answer (score 5):

Restore from backup and try again. Seriously. You really should read up on technologies before deploying them. Check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#DC_Support

A SQL server should NEVER be promoted to a domain controller. It's recommended not to even have the 2 roles on a single server. If you must put them both on the same server, you need to uninstall SQL before DCPROMOing the server. The same goes for IIS. Since you've done an unsupported thing, your best bet is to restore from backup and start over again, this time knowing what's required.

Comment: +1 "read up on technologies before deploying them" - what a novel concept. I wonder if that will take off. ;)